# invalid backend model specified: giftcards/product_additionalprice in magento 1.8

Tags: magento-1.8, import, export

I am using `Magento 1.8` and trying to `export` all producta in **System->Import/Export->Dataflow - Profiles**.

In Profiles i choose **Export All Products** and **Run Profile**.

But it shows error as below

> Invalid backend model specified: giftcards/product_additionalprice
>   [image]

How can i fix this...? Or how to importing/exporting all product without using any `extension`...?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you have uninstalled a module which had created at least one product attribute before. You now have to delete that attribute.

To find it, please use an SQL statement as follows:

`SELECT attribute_id, attribute_code FROM eav_attribute WHERE backend_model LIKE 'giftcards/product_additionalprice';`

After that, you can delete that attribute on the database.