# Magento1.9 categories import error

Tags: magento-1.9, category, import

We are facing the issue While importing the categories

```
The header field store is not a valid one.
```

Can anyone help me how to resolve this issue.

Thanks..!

Comment: Can you please post full error

Comment: Please find the screenshot: https://prnt.sc/gebe9j

Answer (score 2):

It seems you have uninstalled a module which had created at least one product attribute before. You now have to delete that attribute.

To find it, please use an SQL statement as follows:

```
SELECT attribute_id, attribute_code FROM eav_attribute WHERE backend_model LIKE 'giftcards/product_additionalprice';
```

After that, you can delete that attribute on the database.

Reference form [invalid backend model specified: giftcards/product_additionalprice in magento 1.8](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/176417/invalid-backend-model-specified-giftcards-product-additionalprice-in-magento-1/190911#190911)

**Or**

use this https://blog.surgeryxchange.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/import_categories.zip

Comment: Do you have any code to export categories. for magento 1810

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34213371/csv-import-export-problems-in-magento/34267981#34267981 see this post

Comment: We have tried the above link: but exports only category ids not full categories data

Comment: See my answer i give you some link for `mageworks` i hope that will use

Comment: ok Ramesh will try